# Difference between THEME_preprocess_image and THEME_image ?

Tags: drupal-theming

What is the difference between these 2 functions that can but put in template.php for Drupal?

```
function THEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    // something
}

function THEME_image($variables) {
    // something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[function theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) renders the HTML output for a renderable array.

> THEME_preprocess_image

I do believe, that the right name for that is `template_preprocess_HOOK`, it is called inside of `theme()` before theme function eg. THEME_image

Please consider the use case here:

```
// In custom.module     
$variables = array( 
  'path' => 'path/to/img.jpg', 
  'alt' => 'Test alt',
  'title' => 'Test title',
  'width' => '50%',
  'height' => '50%',
  'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
  );
$img = theme('image', $variables);
```

If you want to change some attributes of an image, you do the following:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_image($vars) {
    // Do the changes, before it's rendered.
}
```